# Pass Two Values in For Loop Python

Tags: python, html, for-loop, terminal, flask

I have two Python files and one HTML file. One of the Python files is using Flask to connect with the HTML file.

In `file1.py`(the non Flask one) I set a for loop to print the variable `volume`

```
   for volume in current_volumes:
    print volume
```

which prints out two strings in Terminal

```
 Volume:vol-XXXXXXX
 Volume:vol-YYYYYYY
```

Now I put `from file1 import *` on the top of `file2.py`.
Additionally, `file2.py` contains

`def template(name=volume):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)`

`Index.html` contains
`<p>{{ name }}</p>`

but only reads `Volume:vol-YYYYYYY` when launched.

How do I get it to print out both values of `volume`?

Comment: If ```current_volumes``` contains/produces more than one item, that loop will print all of them.  Maybe ```current_volumes``` only has one item when it gets to the loop.  You may not have posted enough info for someone to help you.

Comment: `current_volumes = conn.get_all_volumes()` if I simply `print current_volumes` it returns `[Volume:vol-e2c979e3, Volume:vol-80942781]
[]
[]` And if I set `def template(name=current_volumes):` it returns `[]`. Maybe Flask has the tendency to use the last part of a list (ie [] and vol-YYYYYYY)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a for loop to create a new string:

```
volume_string = ""
for volume in current_volumes:
     volume_string += volume

def template(name=volume_string):
     ...
```

You can insert a "\n" (newline) at the end of every volume appended to get it to 2 print lines.

I haven't played around with Flask, but you may also want to just try

```
def template(name=current_volumes):
```

Perhaps it's smart enough to make that work.

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Volume' objects`

Comment: current_volumes is a list of Volume objects? Not a list of strings? How is print working? Did you define __str__ in it?

Comment: Pulling list of all volumes from AWS: `current_volumes = conn.get_all_volumes()`

Comment: Also `def template(name=current_volumes):` doesn't work. Tried it before and it spits out `[]`

Comment: Try volume_string += str(volume)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an escaping `for` variable `volume` rather than the list of volumes (`current_volumes`).  (Should you switch to Python 3 this will raise a `ReferenceError` instead of working). Change:

```
def template(name=volume):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)
```

to:

```
def template(name=current_volumes):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)
```

You will also want to change your `{{ name }}` to a loop - let's go ahead and change the name:

```
def template(volumes=current_volumes):
    return render_template('index.html', volumes=volumes)
```

and then add a loop in our Jinja template:

```
{% for volume in volumes %}
    <p>Volume Data: {{ volume }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That just doesn't output anything in the HTML. I don't understand why.

Comment: By the sound of it `current_volumes` is getting overwritten somewhere between where you use it to define a default value for `template` and when you actually *call* template.  Either that or it is a really odd iterator indeed (since the other answer works for you we know that it's not a one-shot iterator).